# Set GPIO value from application

Tags: android

I want to write in a GPIO that is already exported and set as an output, by using the following code :

```
private File file;



public void WriteGPIO(View v) {

    file = new File("/sys/class/gpio/gpio56/value");

    try {
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream (file.getAbsolutePath());
        os.write(1);
        os.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.i("LOG", "write failed : " +e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.i("LOG", "write failed : " +e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I have the following error when I try it :

> write failed : /sys/class/gpio/gpio56/value: open failed: EACCES
>   (Permission denied)

Does someone know if it's possible to have access to the GPIO this way, directly from the app, or if I'm obliged to write a driver to access it?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid you're going to have to provide more info on your problem, like: GPIO for what board?

Answer (score 0):

You normally need to export the pin and set the direction of the pin before you can set it's output state...

```
echo 56  > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo out > /sys/class/gpio/gpio56/direction
echo 1   > /sys/class/gpio/gpio56/value
echo 0   > /sys/class/gpio/gpio56/value
```

Comment: I did the first two steps, directly coded in the kernel so the gpio is exported and already set as an output when the board boots. But I want to control the "value" of the GPIO from my application.

Comment: Run the following command and tell us what you get...
ls -la /sys/class/gpio/

Comment: I get the following : 



lrwxrwxrwx root     root              1970-01-01 06:29 gpio56 -> ../../devices/soc0/soc.1/2000000.aips-bus/209c000.gpio/gpio/gpio56

Comment: Try logging in as root and running the 4 commands I gave earlier on the command line and see if that has the desired effect.  Are you running  your app on some other user account?

Comment: If I run your commands from adb shell, I can see the gpio state changing. I'm running the app without root privilege, that's obviously the problem but I don't know how to give root privilege to my app in the aosp.

Comment: You might need to sign your app as a "system" app in order to access gpio hardware.  I do not know how to do this but there are several threads on StackOverflow about this.

Comment: I signed it to make it a system app (it worked) and I gave full rights to write on the value of the GPIO with chmod 777 but it didn't change anything.